# How should I use VeeValidate 3 for browsers on mobiles?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

Using VeeValidate there seems to be issues with validation of basic forms on mobile platforms.

The forms continue to report errors despite entry being corrected by the user.  There is no problem on desktop browsers.

I'm using vue 2.6.11, vee-validate 3.4.5 and I'm testing using Firefox on a mobile with Android 8 and with Google keyboard.

```
<template>
  <ValidationProvider rules="required|min:2"  v-slot="v">
    <input v-model="value" type="text">
    <span>{{ v.errors[0] }}</span>
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script>
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import {min, required} from "vee-validate/dist/rules";


extend('required', required);
extend('min', min);

export default {
  name: "ValidateTest",
  components: {
    ValidationProvider
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As soon as I start typing I get the error "{field} is not valid"  as expected but the error stays after I have typed more than the minimum 2 characters.  The error disappears if I click anywhere on the page. The error returns if I start typing again, even if there is more than the required 2 characters.

**UPDATE**
This was my first attempt at form validation for mobile browsers.  Reading around it seems that form validation on mobiles involves additional complexities that I had not been aware of.  There's a good discussion [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/four-options-for-mobile-form-validation) (General discussion - not related to Vue.js or VeeValidate).

I will now look at the possibility of handling validation differently depending on whether the user is on a desktop or on a mobile.  For mobile browsers I may just do server side validation and return helpful messages.  I would still appreciate any suggestions of Vue.js validation frameworks that can handle all platforms or techniques that work across browsers...

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced VeeValidate with css classes for validation states and messages that are shown using computed values for each input. The computed values determine if the input value is valid.  This works on mobile without a hitch and is sufficient for the needs of my basic forms.

This is made even simpler using [bootstrap](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#textual-and-value-inputs)